# Ordering divs Jquery

Tags: jquery, sorting

```
<div class="offer">
 <div class="infoffer">
    <div class="dataoffer">
      <div class="offerpay">Pay<br/> $ 67</div>
      <div class="offervalue">Value<br /> $ 160</div>
      <div class="offerdiscount">Discount $ 93</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="offer">
 <div class="infoffer">
    <div class="dataoffer">
      <div class="offerpay">Pay<br/> $ 37</div>
      <div class="offervalue">Value<br /> $ 170</div>
      <div class="offerdiscount">Discount $ 103</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

that is my html code, i want to order(sort) the "offer" divs. i will have 3 buttons, order(sort) by "pay" or order(sort) by "value" or order(sort) by "discount", how can i order them using jquery?. I can change the html but cannot use DB.